# JavaFX FilledOval Alternative for Swing

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

I'm doing a project at university which i decided to do in JavaFX as it is more stylish than Swing, but i'm having difficulty to find an alternative to the FilledOval library for the Canvas AWT as i can't use the Canvas AWT in JavaFX. I'm forced to use the JavaFX Canvas object, which just doesn't work. I need a more object oriented way to put objects on a canvas, not just draw them. Any other alternative? Please share.

Comment: Just create instances of the various `Shape` subclasses (e.g. [`Ellipse`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Ellipse.html)) and add them to a `Pane`?

Comment: The GraphicsContext for a JavaFX Canvas has a [fillOval()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#fillOval-double-double-double-double-) method, why doesn't that work?

Answer (score -1):

JFreeChart had the exact same problem, so created bindings that target JavaFX Canvas while still using Graphics2D API: http://www.jfree.org/fxgraphics2d/.